# Jump to location on page plus extra pixels

Tags: html, css

I have this page with a following menu bar. This bar is X pixels high, so when I choose to jump to a `#div`, it jumps to that div, as if the menu wasn't there, creating the following situation:
[image]

But of course I want it to look like this: 
[image]

The navbar is 90px high, so I'm wondering if it's possible to jump to a div plus a certain amount of pixels. If there is some other solution to my problem, it's of course also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Scroll</a>
<div id="divscroll">Hello World</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#divscroll { margin-top: 5000px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divscroll").offset().top
    }, 1000 / 2);
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ey8ep65x/)

You can get the exact value from the top in jquery by: `$("#divscroll").offset().top`. Now of course you can add or delete from this value.

Comment: I think it will if not just add the that value.. `$("#divscroll").offset().top + 90`

Comment: Nope, I can't get it to work. I even adapted the fiddle so it would look like my page (in buildup with `div`s and `li`s), which still works. But when I try to add it to my page, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: can you share the fiddle with so that I can apply that

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if the javascript is in the bottom of the page, right?

Comment: no this one ` I even adapted the fiddle so it would look like my page `

Comment: Oh wait, I thought jsfiddle would automatically generate a new fiddle. Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/ey8ep65x/1/

Comment: how do you want it to be?

Comment: As you can see, it still works. So I really don't understand why it wouldn't work if I add it to the page. Here's the page: http://xtra.billetten.dk/?page_id=6957. Maybe you can see what's wrong?

Comment: hahaaha that javascript isn't executed check the full width image on the home page `$("#menu-item-6711 a").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#x-content-band-5").offset().top }, 1000 / 2); });` this is visible there

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot the <script>-tags

Comment: Ah, it was missing jQuery. Fixed now.